# How can I get the box inside the buttons?

Tags: css, button, dojo

How can I get the box inside the buttons?
I use dojo toolkit and the button css is as follows:

```
        .button0 {
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 0px;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
            background-color: #ffec64;
            border-radius: 9px;
            border: 3px solid #ffaa22;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #333333;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            outline: none;
            outline-color: transparent; 
        }
        .button0:hover {
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
            background-color: #ffab23;
            outline: none;
            outline-color: transparent; 
        }
        .button0:active {
            position: relative;
            outline: none;
            outline-color: transparent; 
        }
```

[image: buttons]

What I want to remove is the 1px border that has the text.

Comment: where your html? insert pls

Answer (score 2):

can't be sure without seeing the html. I'm assuming the css class is on the button element like so

```
<button class="button0">
```

and that there are no nested element tags.
add:

```
.button0:focus{ outline: 0 }
```

may fix it.
note: for accessibility, its best not to remove the outline.

Comment: Thanks Davies. As you said it has other tags and it must be something of the DOJO themes. There reformulate the question only with the DOJO tag.

Comment: If you right click on the button and inspect you should be able to see the CSS properties.

Comment: Thank you very much Davies. I did what you told me and found the class that needed to be modified.

.dijitButtonNode { border: 0px; }